# Xamarin.Forms - Using StaticResource inside ResourceDictionary

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have a little app in which i have a ContentPage with Syncfusion's SfChat, im trying to customize it a bit, so im using a ResourceDictionary like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <syncTheme:SyncfusionThemeDictionary>
            <syncTheme:SyncfusionThemeDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <x:String x:Key="SfChatTheme">CustomTheme</x:String>
                    <x:String x:Key="SfChatIncomingMessageAuthorFontFamily">MontserratRegular</x:String>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </syncTheme:SyncfusionThemeDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </syncTheme:SyncfusionThemeDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

My problem is that the "SfChatIncomingMessageAuthorFontFamily" property needs a font from my app's resources as a static resource, so how do i use {StaticResource MontserratRegular} instead of just passing the font's name as an x:string ?

Comment: You should set `FontFamily` property with the `SfChatIncomingMessageAuthorFontFamily` defined in the `ResourceDictionary` like        `FontFamily="{StaticResource SfChatIncomingMessageAuthorFontFamily}"`

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT can you provide more details please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exampl,use it on a label：

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <OnPlatform
      x:Key="MediumFontFamily"
      x:TypeArguments="x:String"
      Android="sans-serif-medium"
      iOS="HelveticaNeue-Medium" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

create styles :

```
<Style x:Key="MyLabel" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="FontFamily"
        Value="{StaticResource MediumFontFamily}" />
</Style>
```

then use in label:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource MyLabel}" Text="Hello World" />
```

Comment: in the syncfusion docs, it is mentioned that i need to modify the ResourceDictionary, so i have to insert the staticresource font on the dictionary entry

Comment: It seems that  the `SyncfusionThemeDictionary` class has been provided for automatic merging,when you  define `<x:String x:Key="SfChatIncomingMessageAuthorFontFamily">MontserratRegular</x:String>`,the syncfusion control will use this FontFamily(MontserratRegular).

Comment: Hi @RedZ, if we mention the font family in the string, it will automatically be merging to the desired property in SfChat. Let me know in which platform you are facing the issue?